# What is Lagna and Rashi and their Difference?

Tags: astrology

How is Lagna different from Rashi? As of my understanding - “If Lagna is determined by Sun's position at the time of birth in a Rashi” - then in the Lagna chart why does his position not always be in the house with Lagna?

[image]

In the chart above in the 8th house Lagna is present and if at the same time Sun was there in the same Rashi how can he be in House 2 in the Lagna chart?.

Comment: Only people born at sunrise has Sun in the Lagna. Earth rotates 360degrees each day,across eastern horizon belt which has 27 constellation making 12 houses of horoscope, So each location is in a house for 2hrs/30degrees(12x2=24hrs=360 deg). Also earth takes 360 approx. days to revolve around Sun, so for a specific location, Sun shifts around 1 deg each day,for Sunrise lagna.Rashi is decided by the constellation in which moon is present at birth time. http://www.astrojyoti.com/lagnacalculationbasics.htm This person is born around evening thats why Sun is opposite to Lagna, mid of Krishna Paksha

Comment: @ManuKumar Thanks for the reply but I am still confused, what do we take reference for birth, need more detail and understanding. I have seen the link you provided but still when I imagine I still find the sun always with the lagna rashi.

Comment: First reference in the horizon belt of constellations as its very far from earth and fixed. Second reference is Sun because its fixed for all planets of solar system and this earth. Sun rise in a place is lagna for people taking birth in a place. But not all people take birth at sun rise. Sun moves at 1degree on constellation belt of 12 houses for whole earth, so house of Sun is fixed for a 1month for whole earth but the earth rotates 360 degree every day, so the lagna is unique based on time of day and place of earth and calculated taking Sunrise for that place as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualize through this image. All calculations are made from the earth and we perceive Sun and constellations to be moving, but in reality Sun and distant 27 constellations of eastern horizon belt are static.

[image]

[image]

Earth takes around 360 days(360 degrees) to revolve around Sun. So, Sun remains in a sign made by 27 constellations/12 houses for one month and moves around 1degree across constellation every day as seen from earth. **Makar Sakranti or [Uttarayan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttarayana) is when Sun enters constellation Makara(Capricorn) as seen from earth**. The current Roman Gregorian calendar of 365 days with random month span(28,30 or 31 days) and with a leap year every 4 years is total illogical calendar passed on to Christian nations by popes. Thats why birthdays of every being and their fates(Vedic horoscope) are controlled by spiritual astrology timelines not scientific material astronomy of modern atheist scientists who call it pseudo-science and deny the existence of spirit. Therefore, Hindu festivals like Diwali and birthdays of avatars like Ramnavmi, Jamashtmi which are according Vedic calendar fall on different days of Roman calendar every year. **Actual new year for this earth is not January 1**, which is some ancient local festival of Roman Saturnalia, rebranded as new year by Christians, but around mid-April [Mesha Sankranti](https://blog.onlineprasad.com/mesha-sankranti-day-sun-enters-aries-zodiac/) **when Sun enters Mesha, the first house of zodiac belt** and celebrated as Vaishaki or crop harvesting time as earth enters Vishaka constellation at the same time.

[Lagna Calculation](http://www.astrojyoti.com/lagnacalculationbasics.htm)

> In Vedic astrology the zodiac is centered on the Sun. So Sunrise time
>   at the place of birth is important. This is what determines your Lagna
>   or the ascendant, which is the central keystone of your horoscope.
>
> As Earth takes 24 hours to spin around its axis, all the 12 zodiac
>   signs will rise on the eastern horizon. So in a day there will be 12
>   Lagnas. Hence 24 hrs divided by12 = 2 hours is the time span of each
>   Lagna.
>
> Each sign has 30 degrees. Hence 2 hours = 120 minits divided by 30
>   degrees = 4. So every 4 minits the Lagna increases by 1 degree.
>
> When the place of birth changes, the latitude and longitude also
>   change, sometimes the time zone also changes and because of this the
>   Sunrise time also changes accordingly. This is the reason why Lagna
>   changes from place to place.

So, Lagna is based upon the Sunrise time of location and birth time of the person and date(controlling the sign in which Sun is present). Only those born at Sunrise has Sun in their lagna with Sun Lagna house increasing/rotating sign every 2hrs from Sunrise. While rashi is controlled by Moon sign or Moon projected over constellations.

In the shared example of the horoscope, the person is born when Sun is in 2nd house i.e around May and Sun is in 7th house, so time of day is around evening and Sun is ahead of Moon by 4 houses, so in mid of Krishnapaksha.

Comment: Sir one simple example - from the image you posted, if a person is born on the other side of the earth what will his lagna be? And  What will his lagna be after 2 hours in reference to your image? This will help visualise how lagna and position of sun change in chart. Thank you very much.

Comment: Dont compare positions but time, because reference is Sunrise for all places i.e when that place sees Sun as earth rotates from night to dawn next day. Sun moves 1degree every day across constellation belt, the person born on opposite side had their sun rise around 12 hrs ago, so Sunrise lagna with Sun has moved around 6 houses. People born on same day at same phase of day like sunrise, afternoon but different locations have almost same lagna. Sun and constellations are static, only houses are being rotated based on time of day. Try making example on https://www.astrosage.com/kundli/

Comment: Dear @ManuKumar , Your answer may be correct, But you are wrong at one point. There's nothing in the Universe that is static. Even our Sun revolve around the  centre of Milky-Way.

Comment: @Neck The reference is earth, a man is given a duty to raise his family, not entire society or country, similarly king or minister rules a country, not world or universe. Similarly, Sun is responsible for controlling earth and its limited beings. Only those planets and constellations effect Sun and beings on earth that are seen from the souls taking earth as reference, hence astrology has 7 planets, not Uranus-Pluto seen with telescope.Every person doesn't have to find the end of sky as portrait by modern atheist material science, but the end within self, the truth.

Comment: @ManuKumar I never said your Answer is wrong. I said "You are wrong at one point". Science and Astrology have their own theories. And by the way of science, there are 9 planets(if you include Pluto) and nothing in the Universe is static, that includes The Sun. All the Constellations, all the Galaxies, all the stars etc. everything is moving or revolving.

Comment: @Neck truth is truth, but is matter, your body truth, is it immortal? can science make you immortal, an animal also is attracted to gratify senses and die in end, but do you know what is God, do you know the real purpose of life? Eat, drink and die in end like animals,if you say yes, thats the point where Asuras and Suras separate, Asuras finds pleasure in matter, earth and senses while Suras in Atman. Instead of arguing me with crammed up facts like 9 planets, that you have just read from some books, develop some wisdom, can these baseless facts save you from death, diseases and old age? No.

Comment: @Neck What do you have to do with other stars, millions-billions miles away. Its like an insect boasting of understanding an elephant. Truth is to be find on this earth, not on some other galaxy, your cunningness and facts are useless and burden and so is science of Mlecchas in the end. One who knows one immortal truth i.e Self, knows all, while one who crams facts like parrot from books is destroyed in end. Thats the difference in eternal Wisdom Vedic Spiritually and cramming with intellect, Modern temporary science. I am not here to argue with fact crammers.