# How is each month divided into 27 nakshatra?

Tags: astrology, nakshatra

So I was delving into nakshatra and pada and Rashis and I am confused how is a month divided into 27 nakshatras.

This is what I know so far.

So nakshatras are the lunar mansions (imagine home were the Moon resides) when the Moon (on its rotation around the Earth) crosses the elliptical of the Earth round the Sun. By doing a simple calculation we can see that there would be 27 such crossings (nakshatra) and each spanning for 13.33 degree. So when I imagine a year I imagine it to be 27 nakshatras (with further subdivisions) and each month approximately equal to 2.25 nakshatras.

I was comfortable till then. Then I looked into the panchang of this year and I noticed that every month has all the nakshatras. How is this possible ? What am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37881/20656 You are mixing up solar yearly cycle and lunar monthly cycle. Every month has 2,25 nakshatras because that is according to Sun as sun takes approx 360 days to make 360 degree across constellation belt when seen from earth. Sun remains in 1 out of 12 sign every month, hence 12 months in a year. Moon takes around 27-28 days to cover 12 signs/27 constellations and revolve around earth 360 degrees and hence change constellation every day and sign every 2.25 days which is shown in panchang and controls the correct birth date/horoscope of every person

Comment: Correct birth date/destiny of any person is with the astral Sun comes in the same month and moon in the birth constellation like Buddha Purnima(full moon), Krishna Ashtmi(eight in waning phase) etc.,, not some random date of westernized modern calendar of 365 days with illogical leap year 366 days every 4 years and senseless 30-31 month span born out of rivalry of mortal Roman generals.